# Is Lipschitz condition necessary for a boundary to satisfy segment condition?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

$\textbf{Definition}$: A domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be of class $C^{0,1}$ if for every $x\in\partial\Omega$ there exist $r>0$ and Lipschitz continuous function $\gamma:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that (may change the index of axis if necessary)$$\Omega\cap B_r(x_0)=\{x\in B_r(x_0):x_n>\gamma(x_1,...,x_{n-1})\}$$

$\textbf{Definition}$: A domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to satisfy the "segment condition" if for every $x\in\partial\Omega$ there exist an open ball $U_x$ containing $x$ and a vector $y_x\neq 0$ such that for each $z\in\overline{\Omega}\cap U_x$ we have $$\{z+ty_x:t\in (0,1)\}\subset\Omega$$

$\textbf{Goal}$: Prove that a $C^{0,1}$ domain satisfy the segment condition.

$\textbf{My attempt}$: For $\Omega\in C^{0,1}$ choose $U_x=B_{r/2}(x)$ and $y_x=\frac{1}{3}e_n$ where $e_n$ is the n-th unit vector. From the continuity of $\gamma$ it is clear that for each $z\in\overline{\Omega}\cap U_x$ we have $z_n\geq \gamma(z_1,...,z_{n-1})$ and therefore $\{z+ty_x:t\in (0,1)\}\subset\Omega\cap B_r(x_0)\subset\Omega$.

$\textbf{Question}$: Lipschitz condition is superfluous in my proof to the statement.  Is Lipschitz condition necessary for a boundary to satisfy segment condition?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This definition of class $C^{0,1}$ seems odd in the first place, as it is not invariant under isometries - in $\mathbb R^2$, for example the domain lying underneath a "staircase" does not satisfy the definition (the boundary is not the graph of a function either of $x$ or of $y$), but rotate it $45$ degrees and it does.

Comment: Is it better if "reorienting the axes" is also allowed?

Comment: I don't know about "better", exactly, but it seems odd to essentially allow 90 degree rotations, and no other rotations.  Often in placing conditions on domains we like them to be invariant at least under isometry, so they don't depend on a privileged set of coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lipschitz condition is not necessary for the segment condition to hold; for instance take $\Omega=\{ (a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2: \sqrt{|a|}<b\}$, then it clearly satisfies the segment condition with $y_x=(0,1)$ for any $x=(a,b)$. If instead of segments you have *cones* in a fixed direction and aperture, then this new condition is equivalent to Lipschitz (it's called the interior cone condition).

There is some subtlety here though: Your proof at first glance may suggest that any graph (or rather the domain above said graph, i.e. $\Omega=\{ (x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^n: f(x)<t\}$) will satisfy this segment condition. However, consider for instance $f(x)= \sin(1/x)$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Then $(0,-1)\in \bar{\Omega}$, but any segment starting from this point will intersect the complement of $\Omega$. If your function $f$ is continuous though, then your proof goes through, owing to the fact that $\partial \Omega$ is exactly the graph of $f$ in this case.